# How can I init Materialize in nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, materialize, nuxt.js

I want to use these amazing stuff in nuxt.js, server side render is important.
But the tutorial on the offical website is not so clear, I got some errors.
I run the command 'npm i materialize-css' to install it.
The version below:
"materialize-css": "^0.100.2"

I use the normal way to init the 'dropdown' component, when I move my mouse on the button, or click the button, nothing happend. The 'dropdown' didn't work.

#### html code:

```html
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li>
        <a class="font-color" href="#">
            <i class="material-icons right">chrome_reader_mode
            </i>Blog
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-button font-color" data-activates="drop-list">
            <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down
            </i>Test
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!--dropdown list-->
<ul id='drop-list' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li>
        <a href="#!" class="grey-text">A</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#!" class="grey-text">B</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#!" class="grey-text"><i class="material-icons ">message</i>C
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### Component init code:

```html
mounted() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-button');
        let options={
          inDuration: 300,
          outDuration: 225,
          constrainWidth: true, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
          hover: true, // Activate on hover
          gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
          belowOrigin: true, // Displays dropdown below the button
          alignment: 'left', // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
          stopPropagation: false // Stops event propagation
        }
        var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, options);
    });
}
```

Then I try to init it through jquery, but I got the error either.

> '$ is not defined'. or '$.dropdown() is not a function'

I don't know how to import the jquery and the materialize into my nuxt.js project.
Here is the jquery init code.

```html
mounted(){
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
      inDuration: 300,
      outDuration: 225,
      constrainWidth: true, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
      hover: true, // Activate on hover
      gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
      belowOrigin: true, // Displays dropdown below the button
      alignment: 'left', // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
      stopPropagation: false // Stops event propagation
    });
}
```

The 'nuxt.config.js':

```html
module.exports = {
    css: [
        'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'
    ],
    plugins: [
        $:jquery
    ]
  ......
}
```

Now I have no idea about how to use it in nuxt.js.
Could anybody tell me how I can use it ? I really appreciate it . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Im using this: (nuxt.config.js part, see plugins section):

```

```
css: [
    '~/assets/css/main.css',
    '~node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'
  ],
  build: {
    vendor: ['axios'],
    /*
    ** Run ESLINT on save
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Materialize: 'materialize-css'
      })
    ],
  }
```

```

And now i can init something like select (on any page):
```

```
created () {
    if (process.client) {
      $(document).ready(() => {
        const elem = document.querySelector('select')
        Materialize.FormSelect.init(elem)
      })
    }
  }
```

```

Ofcourse, dont forget to install jquery:
`npm i jquery --save`

Answer (score 2):

In `~/plugins/materialize.js`

```js
import M from 'materialize-css'
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('M', M)
}
```

In `nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  css: [ 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css' ],
  plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/materialize.js', mode: 'client' }]
}
```

Now `$M` can be accessed from context and this in pages, components, plugins, and store actions.

In `example-component.vue`

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$M.AutoInit()
    // will init Materialize
  },
  asyncData({ app, $M }) {
    $M.updateTextFields()
    // If using Nuxt <= 2.12, use 
    app.$M.updateTextFields()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Materialize css don't work with Vue/nuxt properly, it's not supposed to be used with them

You should use [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/)/[vue-material](https://vuematerial.io) with Vue/nuxt.

Comment: But the Materialize css looks so pretty, will it support SSR/Nuxt.js in the future?

Comment: @Kylw.Wilson i dont think so. It will be a complete rewrite. And as I said there already material design frameworks for Vue it's vuetify and Vue material